# Silent Installation of Oracle 11gR2 Fails During NETCA setup in Redhat Linux 8

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, redhat

I am trying to install Oracle 11gR2 in Rhel 8. There was a few incidents of missing packages here and there which I managed to fix during the **SOFTWARE ONLY** installation. But now I am completely stuck during the configuration of NETCA. I am listing the error below:

```
netca -silent -responseFile /database/oracle/database/response/netca.rsp

UnsatisfiedLinkError exception loading native library: njni11
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /database/oracle/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/lib/libnjni11.so: /database/oracle/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1: file too short
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jniGetOracleHome
        at oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.jniGetOracleHome(Native Method)
        at oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.getOracleHome(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCALogger.getOracleHome(NetCALogger.java:230)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCALogger.initOracleParameters(NetCALogger.java:215)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCALogger.initLogger(NetCALogger.java:130)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(NetCA.java:427)

Error: jniGetOracleHome
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
```

What seems to be the problem? Thanks in advance..

Comment: 11g has been out of support for over a year now.  Extended support ended Dec. 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than continue to attempt a hack to get an out-of-support version of the database to run on an operating system version it was never designed to run on, I would advise using a current version of the DB like 19c or 21c. I believe they should run on RHEL 8 with little or no problem. Either that, or if you must have Oracle 11gR2, then use the version of the OS that the database was designed for (RHEL 7).

Comment: You're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

```
libclntsh.so.11.1: file too short
```

You need to run genclntsh

Comment: Thank you. So I ran the script and now it is showing me "Oracle Net Services configuration successful. The exit code is 0". But "lsnrctl status" command is not working. The bash_profile is okay as well. The command Simply does not response. It is not like it shows "command not found" or something.

Comment: I never had "lsnrctl status" returning no output.  As user oracle, cd to $ORACLE_HOME/bin, and run "file lsnrctl" and "ldd lsnrctl".  Since libcntlsh wasn't built, perhaps you need to build the network binaries too.